# Animated background using keyframes and divs - make it fill screen with scroll (html & CSS)

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to use some divs and keyframes to make a moving background for a website. I'm designing for mobile and one some devices there will be some scroll. The problem I run into is that getting the divs to fill the screen with scroll is proving impossible across all mobile sizes. The height of each element on the page is mostly set to auto and I've been using vw for the widths. I've been messing around with the calc function to add some leeway along with a max-height, but really what I want is a unit that calcuates the height of the screen with scroll. Does this exist, and if not, any other recommendations?

Almost forgot, the position of the background is set to absolute. Is there an overflow I can use to make it cover everything?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add javascript in it, which take device-width in px and calculate in vw to apply animation

Comment: How do I get the javascript variable into my css?